# Why my docker report "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock" after colima stopped

Tags: docker, apple-m1, colima

I've installed docker desktop (version 4.16.2) on my M2 macbook, and it nicely works. Then I installed colima (version 0.5.2) to use the gvenzl/oracle-xe image, which only supports AMD64.

Also works fine by `colima start --arch x86_64 --memory 4`.

But after I stop the colima by `colima stop`, and run `docker ps` again, it reports `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` and it only works when I start colima again and `dokcer images` only shows the amd64 images.

The docker dashboard works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you have to tell docker to use the default container.

```
docker context use default
```

When you start colima, it switches docker automatically to the colima context.

Recent versions of Colima revert the Docker context back to default when Colima is stopped, so the `docker context use default` command is no longer necessary.